# how to find words that has 2 consecutive same characters using egrep?

Tags: unix, grep

I tried to do it the brute force way:

```
egrep '[a][a] | [b][b] | [c][c]....' file
```

is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Adding this to favourites for an easy future reminder :) I personally prefer `grep` to `egrep` but it's a small difference.

Answer (score 8):

Use a [back-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

`egrep '(\w)\1' file` will match any two consecutive "word characters".

The `(\w)` creates a "group" that matches any word character.  The `\1` refers to whatever was matched in the first group (which here means the previous character.

```
$ cat test
abcdefg
1234567
abcddefgj
88427

$ egrep '(\w)\1' test
abcddefgj
88427
```

Comment: @JS웃 To be honest, I'd never done this before until this answer. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

`$ egrep '([a-z])\1' file`

([a-z]) - for any character assigns it a number with in the pattern, I believe the numbering starts from 0, and then you are checking if the second letter is same as 1.